# How to access or send local storage data to node / express route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, local-storage

I currently have this route that makes two requests to a mongodb server and then renders them. Except one of them will change when the language is set by the user on the client side.

```js
app.get('/location/:slug', function (req, res) {
    Async.parallel([
      function (callback) {
        var query = Location.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug})
        query.exec(function(err, location) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err)
          }
          callback(null, location)
        })
      },

      function (callback) {
        var query = Location.find({ slug: 'english' }); // language 'english' is set in local storage.
        query.exec(function (err, language) {
          if (err) {
              callback(err)
          }
          callback(null, language)
        })
      }
    ],

    function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.send(400)
      }
      if (results == null || results[0] == null) {
          return res.send(400)
      }
      res.render('pages/single-location', {
        location: results[0],
        setLanguage: results[1][0]
      })
    })
  })
```

What's the best way to access this data to send through the `app.get` route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` doesn't get sent with HTTP requests. Maybe you should consider [using cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) instead, and default to parsing the [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) HTTP header if no cookie exists.

Here are some links for integrating these options with `express 4.x`:

- [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser)
- [req.acceptsLanguages](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.acceptsLanguages)